# Error handling when downloading a file from a servlet

Tags: ajax, servlets, error-handling, extjs4, download

I have a web application that must work with IE7 (yeah i know..) where the frontend is entirely made with ExtJS4, and theres a servlet used to download files. To download a file i send some parameters so i cant simply use `location.href`. it must be a POST.
So far it works, but when an exception is thrown in the servlet i dont know how to handle it to show the user some alert box or some message without redirecting to another page.
In my webapp im also using DWR and im aware of the `openInDownload()` function, but it triggers a security warning in IE. 
So, (finally!) the question is

Using this code:

```
post = function (url, params) {
var tempForm=document.createElement("form");
tempForm.action=url;
tempForm.method="POST";
tempForm.style.display="none";
for(var x in params) {
        // ...snip boring stuff to add params
}
document.body.appendChild(tempForm);
tempForm.submit();
return tempForm;
}
```

is it possible to stay in the same page after submitting ?

or with this other one:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: './descargaArchivoNivs', 
        method: 'POST',
        autoAbort: true,
        params: {
            nivs: jsonData
        },
        success: function(response){
        // HERE!!
        // i know this is wrong
            document.write('data:text/plain,' + response.responseText );
        /*    this looked promising but a warning pops up
              var newwindow = window.open();
              newwindow.document.open();
              newwindow.document.write('data:text/plain, ' + response.responseText );
              newwindow.document.close();*/

        },
        failure: function(resp){
            alert('There was an error');
        }
    });
```

is it possible to open the file download dialog `// HERE!!` with the `response` content??

or is there some other way to open the file download dialog on success, and on failure show a friendly message without losing the users input (the params of the POST) ?

(sorry if this post was too long)

Comment: I have no idea about ExtJS and DWR parts, but I can tell you this: it's not possible to download files by ajax, simply because JavaScript has (thankfully) due to security reasons no facilities to force a *Save As* dialogue with the content of ajax response. You really need to send a synchronous request instead, which can be POST as good. Just invoke `form.submit()` or something.

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you know if it is possible, using `form.submit()`, to stay in the same page after submitting when an error occurs?

Comment: To the point, you just need to redisplay the same page, with the errors embedded. Again, no utter idea how DWR plays a role. Just targeting "basic JSP/Servlet" which you should anyway already be familiar with.